# Why does this tablet's screen stays black when launching an app in debug mode?

Tags: android-studio, adb, archos

I have an Archos Hello 7 tablet running on Android 8.1

When I try to launch the app in debug mode from Android Studio, the app starts but the screen stays black.

Debug mode works fine with other phones or tablet.

Comment: I would check logcat for any exceptions and debug the main activity's `onCreate()` and `onResume()` or `onPostResume()` methods step by step. Otherwise it's a complete mystery also to everybody here as we don't even know your code.

Comment: I've checked and no trace of exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all the breakpoints solved the problem, even though I'm sure that execution was not stopped on a breakpoint when I had the back screen.

To remove all the breakpoints in Android Studio, open

> Run menu -> View Breakpoints...

then select all your breakpoints and hit the Delete button